# Bootstrap change the class on divs when viewing on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to main divs on my site, the left sidebar, and the right div for the content.

In the left div, i have about 50 `<li>`, these are product categories. If im viewing the site on mobile, i have to scroll down a lot to see the product or the content, because the to many `<li>` in the sidebar.

How can i change the divs, that if im on mobile, right div will be the first, and the left sidebar will go down under the right content div. Is there a solution for this?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 custom_right"></div>

<div class="sidebar_main_box col-xs-12 col-sm-3"></div>
```

These divs doesn't have to many css, only float left right, the global bootstrap classes.

**Update**

My classes:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 custom_right"></div>
```

This is the right div, but in the html, this is beforte the sidebar, this:

```
<div class="sidebar_main_box col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
```

My page before the pull and push classes: (good)
[image]

After push and pull classes:
[image]

**What i want, is that im viewing the site on a mobile device, the right div will be the first, and the sidebar will be under the right div, it will be the second div.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the order. The below code will change the divs on smaller devices.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-push-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-pull-9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="col-md-3 left_side col-sm-push-3"><?php if(file_exists("files/right_sidebar.php")) { include_once("files/right_sidebar.php"); } ?></div>
     <div class="col-md-9 right_side col-sm-pull-9">

Comment: Have you added bootstrap?  Please create a fiddle and I will look into it

Comment: Yes its added. I can create sorry. But it doest submit twice every time.

Comment: Hi! I updatied the first post, please see the updates.